# Type Alt Codes on Lenovo Ideapad Yoga13?

Tags: keyboard

I have a LenovoIdeapad Yoga 13, and want to TYPE alt codes. NO CHARACTER MAP OR SIMALAR PROGRAMS. It has no Fn Keypad, and No AltGr.

Comment: It's really unclear as to what you are asking. Are you saying that you have no Alt key at all? I would edit this post and try to make it clearer as to what you are asking so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

Within windows you need a numpad to use alt codes

Your easiest solution would be to use a usb numpad so you don't need to carry a full sized keyboard with you everywhere

**Example:**

[image: USB Numpad]